# Syntax errors in .c file while using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, syntax-error

I'm teaching my brother some C basics, and this is the code:

```
/*Program for cicrumference and surface calculation.*/
#include <stdio.h>                                  // Standard input and output.
#define PI 3.141593;                                // Constant pi.
main() {                                            // Main program.
    double r;                                       // Radius.
    printf("Enter the radius: ");                   // Requesting radius input.
    scanf("%lf", &r);                               // Radius input.
    printf("\nCircumference:    %.6f", r * 2 * PI); // Printing the circumference. // ERR
    printf("\nSurface:          %.6f", r * r * PI); // Printing the surface.       // ERR
    getchar(); getchar();                           // Pause.
}
```

I get these errors:

> error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'

while using the constant `PI` as a part of the expressions in the second parameter of `printf` function.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't put a semicolon for preprocessor `#define`s (nor for any other directive I can remember now, for instance: Do you add a semicolon for `include`s?).

Preprocessor subtitutions are literal, it's inserting the semicolon so the final code is

```
printf("\nCircumference:    %.6f", r * 2 * 3.141593;);
```

which is obviously a syntax error.

Comment: Seems like I'll benefit from repeating the basics with him. :D

Comment: Depending on the compiler you use, you can do `gcc -E` with `gcc` to check post pre-processor result.